# Install SSL certificates in my AWS canary puppeteer script

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to write a script for testing my API which is deployed in AWS EKS in Cloudwatch synthetics (Canary).
But I don't see the provision to add my certificate and key along with my API request.

How can I insert certificate along with the request header of the API?
In my local I am appending the certificates using fs and append it to the axios headers.
If the certificate needs to be append in puppeteer script, how can I achieve it?

### Error message for reference

> ERROR: Request failed. Request: https://myapirequestdns.com/api/v1.0/testroute/testdomain
> ERROR: Failure reason: Error: read ECONNRESET Stack: Error: read ECONNRESET    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)    at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code we use at the top of our canary function running `syn-nodejs-puppeteer-3.5` to retrieve and use a certificate, private key, and CA from AWS secrets manager:

```
const synthetics = require('Synthetics');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const syntheticsConfiguration = synthetics.getConfiguration();

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager();

// We need to load a client certificate to authenticate to endpoints that require mTLS, specified in these env variables
const secretName    = process.env.SECRET_NAME
const keyItemName   = process.env.KEY_ITEM_NAME
const certItemName  = process.env.CERT_ITEM_NAME
const caItemName    = process.env.CA_ITEM_NAME

// Function to retrieve specified key/cert from specified secret and return them as plain strings
const getKeyAndCertAndCA = async function () {
  // Retrieve secret
  const data    = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({SecretId: process.env.SECRET_NAME}).promise();
  // Turn secret string into object
  const secret  = JSON.parse(data.SecretString);
  // Base64 decode the cert and key and return them
  const key     = Buffer.from(secret[keyItemName], 'base64').toString('ascii');
  const cert    = Buffer.from(secret[certItemName], 'base64').toString('ascii');
  const ca      = Buffer.from(secret[caItemName], 'base64').toString('ascii');
  return [ key, cert, ca ];
}
```

Then, just inside the `apiCanaryBlueprint` function, load the key/cert/CA

```
const apiCanaryBlueprint = async function () {
    // Load TLS client cert and key for calls requiring TLS
    const [ key, cert, ca ] = await getKeyAndCertAndCA();
```

and then later, when setting `requestOptions`, specify the `key`, `cert`, and `ca` parameters:

```
      let requestOptions = {
          hostname: url.host,
          method: 'GET',
          path: url.path,
          port: '443',
          protocol: 'https:',
          body: "",
          headers: {},
          key: key,
          cert: cert,
          ca: ca
          };
```

- You must configure your canary environment variables to specify the secret name and what keys (not private key) the certificate, private key, and CA are stored under within the secret;
- The secret item must have the cert, private key, and CA included as base64 strings.